# SQL Server 2008 - How to add NumberofRows and Group By Year

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following code:

```
SELECT  
       CD.tablename, 
       CD.columnname, 
       CD.calculationid, 
       C.name, 
       LCED.period, 
       LCED.value, 
FROM   calculationcolumndependency CD 
       JOIN timedependencies TD 
         ON TD.tablename = CD.tablename 
       JOIN calculation C 
         ON C.calculationid = CD.calculationid 
       JOIN logcomputationevent LCE 
         ON LCE.name = C.name 
       JOIN logcomputationeventdetail LCED 
         ON LCED.computationeventid = LCE.computationeventid 
WHERE  CD.columnname LIKE '%Date%' 
       AND LCED.period IS NOT NULL 
ORDER  BY 6, 
          1, 
          5
```

The following is output of the code:

```
TableName       ColumnName          CalcID  Name                                        Peroid                  Value
dtServiceFee    EffectiveEndDate    1359    SVCFEE 0000 Assign CRD to Payee by Policy   2013-05-06 - Week 04    1
dtServiceFee    EffectiveEndDate    1359    SVCFEE 0000 Assign CRD to Payee by Policy   2013-05-06 - Week 10    296
dtServiceFee    EffectiveEndDate    1359    SVCFEE 0000 Assign CRD to Payee by Policy   2013-05-06 - Week 12    1
dtServiceFee    EffectiveEndDate    1359    SVCFEE 0000 Assign CRD to Payee by Policy   2013-05-06 - Week 20    498
dtServiceFee    EffectiveEndDate    1359    SVCFEE 0000 Assign CRD to Payee by Policy   2013-05-06 - Week 20    0
dtServiceFee    EffectiveEndDate    1359    SVCFEE 0000 Assign CRD to Payee by Policy   2013-07-15 - Week 30    300
```

And the list goes on... (with different tables)

As you can see there is a peroid section (with dates that range from week 1 to week 52 - I just have shown a sample above), and I would like to group up these dates by year (so 2011, 2012, etc), so that all those rows become one single row. However there is a value  as you can see that's associated with each row, I would like all those values to be summed together into a single value (again group by the year - 2011, 2012, etc). Therefore the reason for me to group all these rows together is to find the sum of the values column per year.

Also on top of this I would like a separate column showing the amount of rows from the tables (ex. dtServiceFee) grouped by year.

I want it to look something like this:

```
TableName       ColumnName          CalcID  Name                                        Peroid  Value   NumberofRows
dtServiceFee    EffectiveEndDate    1359    SVCFEE 0000 Assign CRD to Payee by Policy   2012    1   #
dtServiceFee    EffectiveEndDate    1359    SVCFEE 0000 Assign CRD to Payee by Policy   2013    1   #
dtPolicyDetails IssueDate   1966    STLMNT0022 Policies Age During Reserve Period   2011    30  #
dtPolicyDetails IssueDate   1966    STLMNT0022 Policies Age During Reserve Period   2012    30  #
dtPolicyDetails IssueDate   1966    STLMNT0022 Policies Age During Reserve Period   2014    30  #
```

Any help you can provide would be appreciated!

Comment: Please edit your question and provide an example of the results that you want.  Your description is a bit ambiguous.

Comment: Also. On your data example, specify which is every column. Do you have a date column or a varchar column with a date as part of it ?

Comment: I added the changes, and the peroid column is varchar

Comment: Where did "dtPolicyDetails" from?

Comment: Sorry its just another table, the first table I showed you is just a sample of the output (theres 8000 rows). And theres about 8 different tables, where each table encompassing about 1000 rows (cause of the different dates/peroids). So dtServiceFee and dtPolicyDetails are just 2 of the 8. But in the end I would like all 8 to be grouped by year, and since there are multiple years there maybe around 15-20 rows as the output.

Comment: I have explained my question in further detail, please let me know what you think

Comment: Is the period column always going to have the date in that format and at the very beginning of the string?

Comment: Yes It will show up as "2013-03-15 - Week 13" or "2012-01-14 - Week 50" (just 2 possible examples - but always in that format) and is datatype varchar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this. It may not be perfect because your query doesn't reflect your data. For instance you have td.timeid but it wasn't in your output. I used `left` to get the date part of your string. Then turned it into a year and group on that. Here's a really basic sql fiddle showing the logic working

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8a0aa/1)

```
SELECT 
       CD.tablename, 
       CD.columnname, 
       CD.calculationid, 
       C.name, 
       year(left(period, 10)) as period, 
       sum(value) as TotalValue
       count(1) as Cnt, 
FROM   calculationcolumndependency CD 
       JOIN timedependencies TD 
         ON TD.tablename = CD.tablename 
       JOIN calculation C 
         ON C.calculationid = CD.calculationid 
       JOIN logcomputationevent LCE 
         ON LCE.name = C.name 
       JOIN logcomputationeventdetail LCED 
         ON LCED.computationeventid = LCE.computationeventid 
WHERE  CD.columnname LIKE '%Date%' 
       AND LCED.period IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
        CD.tablename, 
        CD.columnname, 
        CD.calculationid, 
        C.name, 
        year(left(period, 10))
```

Comment: sorry I didn't show the complete output, that was my mistake I missed the timeid part.

Comment: Yes I see what you did, I am currently working with it now to see if I can get it working, thank you for your response. I will let you know if I figure it out

Comment: Column 'TimeDependencies.TimeID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. - Any thoughts?

Comment: @user3712641 it means you need to add it to your `group by`. You can't include a column in the select unless you do some type of aggregation on it or like `max`, `sum`, `avg`. For instance I didn't have to add `value` to the `group by` because I performed a `sum` on it.

Comment: Great fixed that problem but now get this: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: @user3712641 More than likely one of your periods does not follow the same format as the others. Maybe there is an empty space in front of one of them or a missing `/`. You can try running this to find it. `select period from logcomputationeventdetail where isdate(left(period, 10)) = 0`

Comment: Yeah you were right, my model had some fields filled with words, so I tried it on a different model and it ran. However, no rows are being returned. I will look into it. Thanks again!